# How to make an exception message safe

Tags: c#, .net, security, exception

I have a diagnostics log which is available for viewing from a view within an MVC application.

The reason for this is that it is difficult to get access to the server, but a dashboard type application can help engineers more easily diagnose issues remotely.

The problem is that this may fail penetration testing as the view includes Exception logging detail. One way of solving this is to not allow logging of exceptions but this will prevent engineers from investigating what caused an error.

So how do I ensure that it is safe enough from prying eyes if the MVC app is compromised? For example, exception logging includes the stack trace which could include sensitive info as to implementation details which could help hackers compromise the system.  Also the exception could include sensitive database information.

Really we need some way of passing the exception through a filter which can trim off possible detail. What is the best/standard approach for achieving this?

Comment: Force authentication before viewing the log?

Comment: @AlexK. There is no auth on the MVC app currently as this is on a server within our own DMZ so it is not visible publicly as such. We may add simple Auth login within IIS. Is this enough though?

Comment: You could apply an ip-filter for the site http://forums.iis.net/t/1153158.aspx?How+to+restrict+a+IIS7+web+site+to+a+specific+range+of+IP+address+

Comment: Since you have no authentication on the server, why not put it on the data? In other words, the dashboard allows the download of strongly encrypted data files that contain the logs and the help engineers can then run an app that can decrypt and display them. That way, all the exception data can be included in the logs.

Comment: Probably if your internal network is compomised, you have more problems than just revealing your stack traces, not?

Comment: @DavidArno I like the idea of that. Its an option I might consider.

Comment: @Evk That is true, but is that response sufficient to get past a penetration test failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We faced a similar problem in a flask (python) app.
We ended up serving a generic error in production, while the error was logged.

Then we added a dashboard, but the dashboard was not visible to every user, instead special permissions where needed.
You could make the dashboard freely available ( e.g. for a testing environment), but the documentation explicitly mentioned the security risks.

Finally, I think educating the customer about the risks is key - for some, having that risk at all is prohibitive, so the deactivate the dashboard and send us the log-files instead. Some can accept some risk, so they activate the dashboard and give us special accounts to access the dashboard. Finally, in some environments the risk is minimal compared to the benefits, e. g. an internal testing environment so everyone can see the dashboard.

As a side note: Another concept I have seen: If a user experiences a problem, his admin can activate tracing for him - e.g. every web service call is collected and saved to a file which can be replayed on a developer pc. Since the data can be highly sensitive - the feature is opt-in and the user sees a "trace" warning while beeing traced. Also, the files are encrypted and deleted after some time.